# Flux.groupBy() followed by Flux#next doesn't group elements

Tags: java, project-reactor

I've observed a behaviour of `Flux#groupBy` that I'm not sure if it's a bug or comes from my misunderstanding of the reactor.

I have a `Flux` with elements that that I want to group by a common field and then return only one element of each group. I've tried to use `Flux#next` but the final result was surprising as I was still getting all elements of the flux.

```
Bar bar1 = new Bar(UUID.randomUUID())
Bar bar2 = new Bar(UUID.randomUUID())

Flux.just(new Foo(bar1), new Foo(bar1), new Foo(bar2), new Foo(bar2))
  .groupBy(foo -> foo.bar.id)
  .doOnNext(flux -> System.out.println("Grouped flux with key: " + flux.key()))
  .flatMap(Flux::next)
  .collectList()
  .block() # the final list here contains 4 elements
```

In the example above `println` is invoked 4 times with key being repeated twice:

```
Grouped flux with key: 8a7b9135-97ce-48d7-a084-97f1bd3b6648
Grouped flux with key: 8a7b9135-97ce-48d7-a084-97f1bd3b6648
Grouped flux with key: 4e174753-0e25-4659-87f9-524f8b0edaf8
Grouped flux with key: 4e174753-0e25-4659-87f9-524f8b0edaf8
```

Replacing a code in `flatMap` to use `Flux#collectList` instead of `Flux#next` has solved the problem for me:

```
Flux.just(new Foo(bar1), new Foo(bar1), new Foo(bar2), new Foo(bar2))
  .groupBy(foo -> foo.bar.id)
  .doOnNext(flux -> System.out.println("Grouped flux with key: " + flux.key()))
  .flatMap(flux -> flux.collectList().map(list -> list.get(0)))
  .collectList()
  .block() # the final list here contains 2 elements
```

I'd expect both snippet to work the same, but clearly for some reason they do not.
What's the explanations of a behaviour like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is that `next()` cancels the open group, so on the following element `groupBy` sees the key1 again, but there's no open group for that key. As a result, it recreates a group and puts the second occurrence of `bar1` into that second group.

With `collectList` there is no such cancellation of the group, so both key1 and key2 groups stay open and `groupBy` is able to dispatch incoming `Foo`s into two groups.

Comment: Hi Simon, 
thanks for clarifying this for me. Is this concept described somewhere in more depth?

Is there other way one could achieve this result without using `collectList`?